# rails: how to add custom json to json output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Whats the easiest way of adding custom json output when you render json? I've seen people override as_json or to_json but they usually exclude attributes or include associations. Is there a way of including plain text?

in my view:

```
def show_json
    show_id = URI.decode(params[:id])
    show_id = show_id.gsub(/\s*$/,'')
    logger.debug "\nshow json: #{show_id}\n"
    @qtls = Qtl.find_by_sql("select * from qtls where qtl_name like '%#{show_id}%' or qtl_symbol in (select qtl_symbol from obs_traits where qtl_symbol like '%#{show_id}%' or trait_name like '%#{show_id}%');")
    render :json => @qtls
end
```

this returns something like:

```
[{qtl: {...qtl attributes..}},{... more qtls }]
```

and I would like to add a a specific field for each qtl. Whats best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

override as_json or use some gem to provide many json templates for example https://github.com/fabrik42/acts_as_api

Comment: Thank you :) This feature of acts_as_api in particular I found useful if anyone is curious: https://github.com/fabrik42/acts_as_api/wiki/Calling-a-method-of-the-model